# join function for a php array

Tags: php

i have an array i want to join into a string using comma(,) separated values.
is there a function similar on the lines of join function in php?

Comment: As it happens, PHP defines an alias for the implode function everyone is talking about.

That alias is called `join`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [`implode(', ', $array)` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Comment: not sure why that answer is better than mine... can someone please tell me?

Comment: @Jacob Relkin: It was first unswer

Answer (score 3):

You can use [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

`$string = implode( ',', $array );`

Likewise, you can then return the string to an array with [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

`$array = explode( ',', $string );`

Answer (score 3):

Say hello to the [implode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) in PHP:

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) function :

```
$your_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$string = implode(',', $your_array);
echo $string;
```

Will get you this output :

```
a,b,c,d
```

Note that '`,`' have been added **between** the array's elements, and not at the beginning nor the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

[implode](http://php.net/implode)